# Como converter um valor (que parece ser octal) para string literal em PHP (5.6)?

Tags: php

Como converter um valor (que parece ser um octal) para string literal em PHP (5.6)?
Exemplo:

```
//considere $mes=08; ou $mes=09;
$mes = 08;

echo $mes; // Retorna 0

$result = (string) $mes;
echo $result; // Retorna 0

$result = sprintf('%o', $mes);
echo $result; // Retorna 0

$result = base_convert($mes, 8, 10);
echo $result; // Retorna 0
```

O valor que "gostaria" de encontrar para $result é `'08'` (String).

Exemplo de uso 1:

```
$mes = (string) 08;

....
public function mesPorExtenso($mes) {

    switch ($mes) {
        case '08': //Não entra no case porque $mes é 0
            $mes = "Agosto";
        break;
    }
}
...
```

Exemplo de uso 2:

```
$mes = 08;

....
public function mesPorExtenso($mes) {
    switch ($mes) {
        case 08: // PHP Parse error: Invalid numeric literal
            $mes = "Agosto";
        break;
    }
}
...
```

**Qual a forma correta de converter o valor 08 para uma string '08'?**

O método mesPorExtenso() é chamado dezenas de vezes, 
O valor é definido por quem o chama. 
Só quero garantir que a variavel `$mes` seja uma string.

Comment: Primeiro, eu acredito que vc não queira converter um octal para String, mas um número para String. Octal é um sistema de base 8, ou seja, tem representação com os números de 0 a 7.

Comment: Não faz sentido você declarar a string como `$mes = (string) 08`, seria mais fácil declarar direto como string

Comment: Como o @WallaceMaxters falou, não faz sentido mesmo vc declarar desse jeito. E, pelo que eu entendi, o PHP não está aceitando o número com o zero na frente. Se vc quer completar com zeros a esquerda, pode usar a função [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php) do PHP.

Comment: @eliangela ah, faz sentido. Talvez seja a dúvida dele. Se quiser preencher com `0` na frente, use a função `sprintf` com o a quantidade de `0` desejado. Exemplo: `$mes = sprintf('%02d', 8)`

Comment: A variavel $mes, nesse caso, vem de inputs externos, ou seja, não declaro diretamente a variavel. Ela já vem com o "0" na frente, com os valores: 07, 08, 09, 10, 11 ou 12. É justamente essa a questão.

Comment: Ronaldo, o exemplo não se aplica, mas o que você quer ? Para que quer converter um valor, que a linguagem não aceita?

Comment: @WallaceMaxter, Os valores 08 e 09 não podem ser convertidos para string. A linguagem não aceita essa conversão. Essa é a resposta definitiva?

Comment: Sim. E sinceramente, não entendo para que você quer definir um valor como `int` para obter um `string`, sendo que você já pode definir uma `string` diretamente. Além do mais, dependendo do que você quer fazer, poderia estar ganhando tempo fazendo de uma forma mais fácil (ou menos complicada).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters imagine a seguinte situação:
**
public function mesPorExtenso($mes) {
    switch ($mes) {
    
        case '08': //Não entra no case porque $mes é 0
             return "Agosto";
        break;    
    }    
}
**
Imagina que esse método é usado por centenas de classes. como eu garanto que mês é uma string

Comment: Dizer que 08 ou 09 é um número octal é o mesmo que dizer que 02 é uma representação binária, que o dia 32 do mês 15 existe, que agora são 25 horas e 75 minutos, etc. São valores matematicamente impossíveis para as suas respectivas bases. No seu caso exibe 0 pela filosofia do PHP de nunca dizer ao desenvolvedor que ele está errado.

Comment: `is_string($mes)`? `strlen($mes) == 2`? cara, existe mil formas de fazer isso [fácil] em php. Com todo respeito, mas você está complicando. Além do mais, porque não usa uma representação numérica no `case` e converte o que você recebe para `int`? Seria fácil demais resolver isso.

Comment: `$mes = (int) $_GET['mes']`... Daí em seguida, você usa um `array` de meses.

Comment: O titulo dá a entender que o problema é com octal, mas me parece que na verdade o problema aí é outro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, $mes = (int) 09; echo $mes; // retorna 0;

Comment: A resposta que procura é: não use `08` (valor não existe), use `"08"`.

Comment: @ronaldorodrigues cara, cara! qual é a dificuldade de alterar o código para ele receber int? Você está gastando muito tempo numa coisa que quase ninguém faria. A sua solução parece estar mais complicando que ajudando.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Os valores 08 e 09 não podem ser convertidos para string. A linguagem não aceita essa conversão. Essa é a resposta definitiva?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é usar o `0` ao declarar o mês. Do seu servidor web você já irá receber o valor em *string*, então só nos casos que você colocar diretamente no código terá problemas.

Para funcionar corretamente, declare já como *string* `$mes = '08'` ou use o inteiro sem o zero `$mes = 8`.

Referencia na documentação do PHP: [Inteiros](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Eu estou tentando explicar isso a duas horas, kkkkkkk

Answer (score 4):

Quando você insere o 0 na frente de um número, ele é considerado um octal. O problema é que no caso dos valores `08` e `09`, nas versões anteriores ao PHP 7 ignoram o resto do número. A partir do PHP 7 um erro de conversão será emitido.

> Aviso Em versões anteriores ao PHP 7, se um dígito inválido é passado
>   para inteiro octal (por exemplo, 8 ou 9), o resto do número será
>   ignorado. Desde o PHP 7, um erro de interpretação é emitido.
>   Informação em https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php

Para funcionar o que você deseja, é necessário que seja passada uma String.